# How to get an object with a similar tag using django

Tags: sql, django, tags

I have an object (a blogpost) which can have multiple tags in django. I'm trying to get related objects with one or more of these same tags.

For example: You have a blogpost with a few tags, like 'food', 'drinks' and 'restaurants'. When you open this blogpost, there are displayed some 'related' blogposts (meaning they share one or more tags). An example of such a related blogpost would have the tags: 'soda', 'lemonade' and 'drinks'.

Here is my view:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id)
tags = instance.tags.values()
related = []
for x in tags: #to put all the tags in an array
    related.append(x['name']) 
for a in Blog.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM "blog_table" WHERE related in "blog_table"."tags"'):
    print (a.name) #this should display the name of all the related blogposts (probably including itself)
```

Here are my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.number) + ' ' + self.name



class Blog(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=500, verbose_name='title of blogpost', unique=True)
body = models.TextField(null=False, verbose_name='body of the blogpost')
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the blogs that have similar instance tag, you can do this:

```
tags = instance.tag.all()
for tag in tags:
    print(Blog.objects.filter(tags=tag))
```

Comment: Aren't you then assuming that a blog only has one tag while doing Blog.objects.filter(tags=tag)?